# Django 2.2 AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-2.2

I read some reviews in AWS forums they said some people Django 2.2 and python 3.6 possible to AWS deployment but in this mean while most of the people said 2.1 only work not 2.2. so i want some clarification about which Django version should i use to AWS. i already test 2.2 it is not working state but 2.1 fine.

Answer (score 0):

The aws documentation:

- [Deploying a Django application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)

Indicates Django **2.1.1**. This could explain why you found tat 2.2 is not working, but 2.1 is.